# How to get session id from cookie?

Tags: java, android

I take away all the cookies, and what I get is: **JSESSION=234234fsdf23**.
 But I only need a value without **JSESSION**.
 Please tell me how to do this?

```
  Headers header = response.headers();
  List<String> cookieList = header.values("Set-Cookie");
  String jsessionid = (cookieList.get(0).split(";"))[0];
```

Comment: Check this answer i guess help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987481/getting-sessionid-without-accessing-the-session-using-cookies-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it this way:

```
String header = response.headers().get("Set-Cookie");
       String arr[] = header.split("=");
       String jsessionid = arr[1];
       jsessionid = jsessionid.substring(0,jsessionid.length()-5);
```